# Getting the last created document Cloudant/CouchDB thorugh NodeJS

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cloudant

I would like to get the last inserted document in the database through the Cloudant npm module in NodeJS but i haven't found anything that would help in the documentation.

Is there a way to do this directly from the db.get document function? I don't have a timestamp key on the db document so I can't manually sort by that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudant/CouchDB doesn't timestamp a document so it has no notion of "last created". Which leaves you with two client-side solutions which you mention:

1. Add a timestamp into your JSON when you create document. e.g.

   {
     "username": "glynn",
     "timestamp": 1525245671509,
     "level": 4
   }

You can then [query](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#query) the database or create a [MapReduce view](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/creating_views.html#views-mapreduce-) that orders the documents by the timestamp.

2. If your application allows, your document `_id` field could begin with a timestamp e.g. `1525245671509-user:glynn`. This would allow you to query the [_all_docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/database.html#get-documents) endpoint to fetch the last inserted document e.g.

`GET /db/_all_docs?descending=true&limit=1&include_docs=true`